# Android webview loadurl("file:///android_asset/index.html#home") failed

Tags: android, webview

I am working on an application in Android, where I want to load a local html file using

```
webview.loadurl("file:///android_asset/index.html#home");
```

It will load ok on most devices, but on some Samsung devices with Android OS 4.0.4 , it load fails.

Do you have ideas with this issue?

Add some comments and sorry for my mistake just now.

```
webview.loadurl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

work fine  , but

```
webview.loadurl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html#home");
```

failed .

Comment: In some devices , if the link inlcude '#' , the webview loaded failed and displayed can not found the page .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First check that **index.html** is under asset folder in your project folder.

I believe it is under **www** folder within asset folder of your project.

1:First put **index.html** under **www** folder

2:put the **www** folder within **asset** folder and call

```
webview.loadurl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

**Edited:**

I think you might want to call the **home** tab of the index.html every-time when you will run the application.

As android is only concern of the html pages not the tabs here is a good way which may help you i.e.

**Set the home tab active of your index.html and make other inactive.**

This will might help you.

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake , the index.html file is under my-project/assets/www/ . And webview.loadurl("file://android_asset/www/index.html"); work fine , but webview.loadurl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html#home"); failed .

Comment: So if my answer helps you accept it. It may help other users. @binkery

Answer (score 0):

this is what happen to me i misspelled it make sure you typed correctly

file://android_asset/www/index.html

not as  "assets"

Comment: That's not an answser. OP didn't type "assets"

Comment: This answer looks to be missing a `/` as well