# WebView load from Asset

Tags: android, webview, cdn, mathjax

I have put a LaTex script which I render using MathJax CDN. This is the code I used: 
[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView wq;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView wv;
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.qtext);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///asset/circleeq.html");   
    }
}
```

It was displaying on my android some weeks ago without any issue, but today its does not show. Help me why?

My HTML script:
[image: enter link description here]

ERROR here:

`E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver
E/AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/circleeq.html`

Comment: Any error exceptions ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857225/android-webview-loadurlfile-android-asset-index-htmlhome-failed

Comment: I tries putting it in "www" folder, it then displays: `"Webpage not available"`

Comment: Added my html script code at my original question. Has it got something to do with LaTex which i am using?

Comment: Search on google .`Unable to open asset URL:`

Comment: Nothing is helping. :(

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I added a picture of the file in my asset folder, based on that is my file location correct in the code? `wq.loadUrl("file:///asset/circleeq.html");` ??

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the javascript. Try to run the app removing the the javascript inclusion part. If it wotks fine then the problem is with the **URL of the javascript**. Makesure it is fine.
If you are using cordova, i think the *URL*s are case sensisitive.