# How to save files from assets using webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-file, android-storage

I'm using webview to make android apps. All works ok with my page but a have some files in assets I want the users can save from the page.
I try to give some permitions for my app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and my MainActivity.java have this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView web= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.dweb);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");}
```

So, I have a link from my html file in assets wish point to the file I want the user download, but the web allways shows an error such as `the file don't exist` or something

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/19857413/9408181

Comment: Thats not my problem. The html looks ok in my app, is the file that I want the user download that the webview cant find. is a zip archive and I want the system handle it and allow to download.